# Не могу синхронизировать доступ к элементу управления из разных потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Имеется собственный компонент для построения графиков. Требуется, чтобы 3 потока добавили в этот график по функции, а затем добавляли точки в массив данных.

Проблема в том, что я никак не могу синхронизировать эти действия. Что бы я не делал - использовал `lock` или `Monitor`, потоки всё равно выполняют действия в беспорядке. В итоге у меня постоянно выскакивает `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` - либо не заполнена коллекция графиков, либо не заполнена коллекция данных графика. Больше у меня никаких идей нет.

Код главной формы:

```c#
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    delegate double MathFunc(double x);
    MathFunc [] functions = new MathFunc[] { Math.Sin, Math.Cos, Math.Tan };
    Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green };
    object obj = new object();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //lineChart1.YTitle = "yyyyyyy";
        //lineChart1.XMin = -5;
        //lineChart1.XMax = 10;
        lineChart1.YMax = 5;
        lineChart1.YMin = -5;
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(ThreadFunc);
            thread.Start(i);
        }
    }
    private void ThreadFunc (object i)
    {

        int ii = Convert.ToInt32(i);
        if (lineChart1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            lock (obj)
            {
                LineChart.Curve curve = new LineChart.Curve(new List<PointF>(), new Pen(colors[ii], 2.0f));
                lineChart1.BeginInvoke(new Action<LineChart.Curve>(lineChart1.Curves.Add), curve);
                for (int j = 0; j <= 100; j++)
                {
                    float x = 0.1f * j;
                    lineChart1.BeginInvoke(new Action<PointF>(lineChart1.Curves[ii].Data.Add), new PointF(x, (float)functions[ii](x)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Код проекта целиком находится здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/9B-Oskgxz6a4A).

Comment: Если вы выложите нужную часть кода в вопрос, те люди, которым лень скачивать проект и разбираться в нём, тоже смогут помочь.

Comment: @VladD А вдруг дело не в той части кода, о которой я подумал, и ошибка кроется дальше?

Comment: Это конечно может быть. Но разбираться во **всём** проекте захочется, поверьте, куда меньшему числу участников.

Comment: Посколько `BeginInvoke` всего-лишь ставит операцию в очередь на выполнение в UI потоке, и не ожидает ее завершения, ваш `lock (obj)` абсолютно бесполезен. Я предлагаю подготовить `LineChart.Curve` вместе с `Data` заранее (в фоновом потоке), а в `BeginInvoke` отправить уже полностью сформированную кривую.

Comment: @Raider, а как быть, если нужно нарисовать кривую по кусочкам? Надо же как-то проиллюстрировать совместную работу потоков... Или для этого придётся перепроектировать весь `LineChart`?